No response from javascript frida
I'm currently trying frida and using https://github.com/httptoolkit/frida-interception-and-unpinning/ as a tutorial, but unfortunately frida isn't working. Im using a Samsung Galaxy S9 (https://www.devicespecifications.com/de/model-cpu/066948b6) so a rooted physical device.
frida version: 16.2.1, I have also tried frida 15.2.2, client and server of course.
C:\Users\###\Downloads\platform-tools-latest-windows\platform-tools>frida --debug -U -f tech.httptoolkit.pinning_demo -l frida_multiple_unpinning.js
     ____
    / _  |   Frida 16.2.1 - A world-class dynamic instrumentation toolkit
   | (_| |
    > _  |   Commands:
   /_/ |_|       help      -> Displays the help system
   . . . .       object?   -> Display information about 'object'
   . . . .       exit/quit -> Exit
   . . . .
   . . . .   More info at https://frida.re/docs/home/
   . . . .
   . . . .   Connected to SM G960F (id=2252a1780a037ece)
Spawning `tech.httptoolkit.pinning_demo`...

also Objection is an tool for injecting code but also no response:
C:\Users###>objection --gadget tech.httptoolkit.pinning_demo explore
Using USB device SM G960F


Spawning an app via Frida can be a bit fragile. If you have problems execute adb shell killall frida-server (assuming you use Frida Magisk plugin which automatically restarts frida-server).

I tried the magisk plugin but I am using the normal frida-server file and starting the server by hand and unfortunately this didnt help.

I used instead ./frida -p [PID] -s script.js for testing
